# Mariadb UPDATE extremely slow from remote client

Tags: mysql, linux, mariadb

I have a perplexing issue with extremely slow row updates being performed from a remote mariadb user:

- SELECT is fast for `127.0.0.1` (0.05ms)
- UPDATE is fast for `127.0.0.1` (0.05ms)
- SELECT is fast for `10.0.0.1` (0.09ms)
- UPDATE is EXTREMELY SLOW for `10.0.0.1` (30 seconds)
- iptables is off

  - in any case, a networking issue is not consistent with fast SELECTs for `10.0.0.1`
- Table has low activity and is not locked

  - in any case, a table traffic issue is not consistent with fast UPDATEs for `127.0.0.1`

**I am completely stumped** because the issue appears irrational.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update/Fix**

It turns out the table just needed to be analyzed (`mysqlcheck -o --all-databases`). I suspect it was due to an index issue related to recently loading the table from an SQL file, where the original mysqldump command specified options `-e` and `-K` to optimize the table the import speed.

Comment: Can you give an example of the `UPDATE` query that's slow?

Comment: Are the client and the query the same from both 127.0.0.1 and 10.0.0.1? And what is the status of the query during these 30s? (You can check it with a "show processlist" instruction)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replies. I think I figured it out, and will update my question shortly - all tables just needed to be repaired and analyzed using mysqlcheck. It still doesn't explain why UPDATEs were fast from localhost ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Are the tables MyISAM or InnoDB?

Comment: What is the setting of `skip-name-resolve`?